# Programatically add tab to fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a site where people can log in and link their FB fan page. When they link their fan page, I save the pageId and an auth token, which I then pass to FB API to post to their wall.

What I would like to be able to do is have a button on my site which, when clicked, would add a new tab that is essentially an iframe with a url to their profile page on my site.

Looking around, I've only seen examples that reference an application Id. I get the impression that this application Id is not the id of my application, but that instead that each user needs to create an application of their own, and then I can set the page url of that application, which is way too technical for my audience.

Preferably, the entire process can take place within my site and the call would be something like:
{fbEndPoint}/newTab?authinfo={their token}&pageId={fbPageId}&url={urlToTheirProfilePageOnMySite}

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question...

What I wanted to do was have a way of knowing what custom page from my site to display when the tab was selected. I figured that when the tab was added, I needed to provide the URL to their profile page on my site. What I did not realize, was that when adding a tab to a fan page, what is really happening is that my app is being added to the tab and the URL that will be displayed in the iframe is the "Page Tab Url" from my app settings.

When someone visits the tab, Facebook provides me with the page Id of where the app is being viewed in the signed_request parameter. Using the pageId form the provided signed_request param, I can then look up which custom page to show on my site, since I know which member installed my app in the provided pageId.

Hope that helps someone!